# How to make Rails stop logging every page rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

On my production server I get thousands of

```
Started GET ... Completed 200 OK
```

In production.log

This definitely eats resources: Rails needs to write this unnecessary info down, and it takes precious server space.

Besides I want to see only error reports and my own logger.info/error calls.

How can I disable rendering logging?

Comment: Disk is cheap and it doesn't eat as many resources as you think it does.

Comment: @Eric disk is cheap, disk thoughput is not.

Comment: I was referring to, "...and it takes precious server space."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at your `config/environments/production.rb` file for the `config.log_level` variable.

Keep in mind however, that on a database failure, you can use the info statements to recreate data lost via user input between last db backup and database restore.

other tips and suggestions [here](http://maintainablesoftware.com/articles/rails_logging_tips)

Comment: You probably want to have a better database disaster recovery strategy than relying on the rails log files to restore your database.

Comment: It's also good to have options in case your recovery strategy springs a leak.

Comment: I was referring to a very last case situation. We backup our production database every four minutes and we have duplicate writes to two instances of mySQL and there was a scenario last year where we needed to restore data from log files for about two minutes of downtime. It took about 4 hours but we didn't loose anything.